# Using both clock edges in an FPGA design

Tags: fpga, clock, xilinx, timing-analysis

So, after getting some advice from some good people here, I managed to put together my first (very modest) FPGA design. It is basically just a few registers and counters, and only runs at a few MHz, but I could synthesise and implement it with no warnings, and the real signals coming out seem to do what simulation made me think they would. I learned a few things along the way.

Now I want to learn how to set timing constraints and run timing analysis. So I am reading through the Xilinx doc [UG612](https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/sw_manuals/xilinx14_7/ug612.pdf) and I see at the top of page 205:

"Use only one edge of the clock"

Hmm. Seems I broke the law. Part of my design is a parallel load shift register - I used the negedge of the last cycle of the clock to load it (from a counter which was clocked on the previous posedge). A quick sketch:

[image: clocking and loading]

Of course, I am not directly using the negedge here, but the load signal is derived from it. I thought that this was good - but Xilinx tells me - don't do that.

Am I wrong? If so, why? What should  I do instead?

Comment: The error xilinx gives you is about a gated clock ?

Comment: no, my design compiles completely cleanly - no warnings or errors. I am referring to advice given in the linked document (page number in text above).

Comment: You can mix them, but from a timing perspective that means that the setup/hold paths become half as long, and timing becomes harder to meet. What is SRCLK derived from?

Comment: SRCLK is a 2MHz clock, the main clock of my design. (There is a 100MHz crystal oscillator on the dev board, I used a synchronous counter to get the 2MHz.) I figure at these frequencies there is unlikely to be a problem, but I would like to know what is "best practice" and why.

Comment: The output of your counter is not a 2 MHz *clock*. It's a square signal with 2 MHz but no (real) *clock* signal. In general most FPGAs do not support slow clocks below 10 MHz. You should operate you circuit with 100 MHz and generate a clock enable signal with a 2 MHz frequency.

Comment: BiPhase clocks are useful in reducing latency by 50% but if the setup/hold time requirements are met asynchronous input frequency can be doubled using the same edge

Comment: FPGAs do not support DDR techniques (working on both clock edges) for internal flip-flops. This is only supported for Input/Output Blocks (IOBs). If you have system clock of 100 MHz, use the enable technique as described above. This allows you to use up to 50 shifted version of your 2 MHz signal instead of one shifted version (25th order).

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and advice. Paebbels - I am not actually clocking any device off *both* edges - however I am using negedge clock on some devices. Do you have any link to the CE technique? And when you say "most FPGAs do not support slow clocks below 10MHz" - what does that really mean? what are the (possible) consequences? and when exactly does a square wave become a "proper clock"?

Comment: @Paebbels *"most FPGAs do not support slow clocks below 10 MHz"* I understand the PLL may not be able to generate slow clocks, but what would prevent the FPGA to proceed at this slow speed if the clock is externally generated (or even internally using some frequency divider logic)? Do you have references for this constraint?

Comment: Real *clocks* are not routed with user logic resources, but with (clock) dedicated routes - so called clock networks. There fore you need to feed the *generated clock* into a `BUFG`, `BUFH`, `BUFR`, ... You cannot use such a *combinatoric* clock for any clock modifying block (CMB) as an input. At next you need to specify new constraints in the system to notify the static timing analysis that this signal has a frequency, duty cycle, and maybe phase relationship. Normally, such constraints are inferred automatically.

Comment: I have never seen any student nor engineer doing all this when they use the dirty way of creating derived clocks. Ok, next problem, the user logic (counter) used generate the clock introduces a high jitter into the signal. There fore again one needs to specify timing constraints, but the maximum jitter in FPGAs for this technique in unknown. It's also very temperature and voltage (workload) dependent. Engineers using this dirty method for slow designs will use the same technique for higher frequencies or in multi-gigabit transceiver designs. So there is a very simple design rule - don't do it!

Comment: This can also be found in the vendors' HDL design guidelines...

Comment: I think that ISE is aware that these are clock signals : "1 clock inputs: 
   i_clk_100MHz 
  
 4 leaf clock nets: 
   clk_div/o_clk_BUFG 
   i_clk_100MHz_BUFGP " - thanks for your comments. As I say - I am learning.

Comment: So, I found out that by using the clock wizard in ISE I can generate a 4MHz clock from the 100MHz, which is fine, using the internal  clock resources. (The lowest it can go from 100MHz clk in is just over 3MHz - if my external clock was 20MHz, I could easily generate an internal 2MHz of course.) Of course this is better than what I was doing - another thing I learned. I also looked at the datasheet and I see no spec for minimum clock frequency anywhere at all. Plenty of Fmax, no Fmin. Of course, if anyone knows of such a requirement in the Xilinx Spartan 6 data, I would be interested to know.

Answer (score 2):

> "Use only one edge of the clock"

I don't know why they would say that. You can use both rising and falling clock edges in the design and the timing analyser will take that into account.

Thus a 200MHz clock will give you 5 ns from rising edge to rising edge but only 2.5 ns from rising edge to falling edge. I made a small example using 16 bit values:

```
always @(posedge clk)
   result1 <= counter + hold;
always @(negedge clk)
   result2 <= counter + hold;
```

Below is a screenshot of the ISE timing analysis. It is for a 5ns 50% duty cycle clock.

The text is about a failing path from bit 3 of `counter` to bit 15 of `result2`. As you can see it uses the rising edge as source and the falling edge for the destination.

[image]

Comment: I think they say it to prevent anymore SR tickets... and, because KISS is better anyway.  But, yeh, completely valid to use different edges, and their timing tools can handle it

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, it does seem it can be done - but as Photon points out below - that doesn't mean it should be.

Answer (score 1):

The logic elements in the FPGA are usually designed with *zero hold time*, specifically to enable you to design with only one clock edge.

In your example, this means that both the CTR INC signal and the SR LOAD signal are seen as asserted on edge 0, and neither one is seen as asserted on edge 15. The value that gets loaded into the shift register will be the one that is in the counter prior to edge 0. The effect of incrementing the counter won't be seen in the shift register until the next time SR LOAD is asserted.

If you made the SR signal follow the same waveform as CTR INC, this would still be true, and the circuit behavior would be the same.

Comment: Right. This is very helpful, because this is where I was not thinking quite straight. When I did this I was worrying about the SR skipping a count if I would use the same signal. This won't happen as FPGA's flip flops are not yet able to predict the future. Reassuring!

Answer (score 1):

You are not wrong, you are just making your life more difficult than it needs to be...  especially where timing closure is concerned (developing accurate constraints is harder).  You can easily make this design operate on rising edge only.

Seems to me, if you want to load when counter = 0, you could have some combinatorial logic that: `assign load = (counter==15)` (or similar).  This will shift your load signal back 1/2 clock cycle, and be seen on the rising edge of edge0 as asserted.  There are many ways to do this (using all rising edge clocked FFs) though, and probably a little googling will go a long way.